# Can't click on a login button using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I try to login to this page through selenium.

```
https://cloud.fitbulut.com/kullanici/giris
```

I can enter my password and username via selenium but cannot make it to login by clicking on the button named 'Giris'.

I have tried this one but it gives `NoSuchElementException` error.

```
driver.find_element_by_class("btn btn-primary btn-aut").click()
```

Looking forward to any help or suggestion. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using XPATH. For your case it is; 
`/html/body/app/main/kullanici/giris/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[3]/div/button/div`

Comment: thank you very much it worked but I do not understand this. Which subjects should I study on to be able to understand this? Sorry I'm a total newbie.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean is `.find_element_by_class_name` not `.find_element_by_class`.

`.find_element_by_class_name` just for single class name, and element you mean having multiple classes i.e `btn btn-primary btn-auth`. Instead you can use css selector:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn.btn-primary.btn-auth').click()
```

[Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)